# build color library using partials and variables

Tags: sass, less, scss-mixins, scss-lint

_lists.scss this is color lists file

```
$text-color_white: #fff;
$text-color_black: #000;
```

_typo.scss this is styles file

```
@mixin textsize($selectors...) {
  @for $i from 0 to length($selectors) {
    .title-#{nth($selectors, $i + 1)} {
      font-size: #{nth($selectors, $i + 1)} + px;
    }
  }
}
@include textsize("16");
```

i want to map the colors in to typo.scss and i want output like this

```
.title-16 {
  font-size: 16px;
}

.title-16-text-color_white {
  font-size: 16px;
  color :#fff;
}

.title-16-$text-color_black{
  font-size: 16px;
  color :#000;
}
```

can any one help me how to map the color from another partial and inject that in to typo.scss to generate the final output like the one i provided above.